# How to change default browser?

Tags: personalization

I found in the Marketplace two extremely good browsers and I want use one of them as default browser. I want to open links in browser that I will choose by myself. How I can do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't change the default browser as it has been built in with the assumption people wouldn't be spending time on making alternative browsers (that are based on IE anyway) in the market place. The closest you can come to this is to developer unlock your phone and find something that is similar to [this application](http://www.xda-developers.com/windows-mobile/ie-search-switcher-for-wp7/), but I doubt if that exists...

Answer (score 3):

If you have an Unlocked Windows Phone , I will strongly suggest you to try the Windows Phone Hacker Tweaks which brings in lot of customization including what you need.

http://windowsphonehacker.com/articles/app_wph_tweaks-04-09-12

Comment: The tool you suggest is cool. But it doesn't allow me change default browser. It only open opportunity to set Google as main search engine. This is not exactly I need.

Comment: I saw around unlocking windows phone and make conclusion that unlocking is possible only if I have full developer registration with annual paymen Am I right or not?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Microsoft may soon let you change the default browser of your Windows 10 Mobile phone]

Microsoft’s Edge app now features a setting which – in theory – should allow you to select your default web app. Of course, the option doesn’t do much now.
("Now" is Oct. 15, 2016. This feature is first introduced in Win10 Mobile RS2 Insider Preview 14946/Edge 39.14946.1000.0)

Comment: Could you clarify the "now" part? What OS/Edge version was this introduced in?